# Functionality of StackExchange behind a Corporate Firewall

Tags: support, voting

I generally only access StackExchange at work.  Sadly, I have to go through some sort of proxy server/firewall thing to get to the internet.  I just found myself unable to vote on questions and answers.  Did StackExchange change something, or did my corporate firewall?  Just wondering so I can track this down on my end.

Comment: did you try clearing your browser cache? Also what browser?

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the links below:

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js
- http://sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=778aaf5a38e2

Both should result in pages of script. If either one results in an error, that's your problem.

Also do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, just in case you're stuck with a bad cache.

Comment: jquery 1.5? Holy old version batman. Edit: Phew, you got the version wrong- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js is referenced here and SO.

Answer (score 1):

From work, I have a similar problen. The "close" button doesn't work on Chrome. Works of FF and IE9.

Both the js work from here.

Maybe it's related...